# Kendo js Grid make header cell filter reflect menu filter

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

## **MCVE**

You can observe the described issue in the following [example](https://dojo.telerik.com/ImejuXUD/2).

## **Setup**

I have a grid and a column that can be filtered both by header column cell and fitler menu.

The config for grid is the following:

```js
filterable: {
   mode: "menu, row"
}
```

The config for the particular column is like this:

```js
filterable: {
   multi: true,
   cell: true
}
```

## **Steps to reproduce**

1. Open column filter menu with checkboxes and select 2 items (e.g. "Nancy" and "Andrew"):[image]
2. Press 'Filter' button in that menu.
3. Observe that in header column cell filter only "Nancy" (1st item) is specified there:[image]

## **Problem**

The filter works great but there is this noticeable UI issue that only 1st item (e.g. "Nancy" in this case) is shown in the header filter cell.

The question is there a way to make it show all selected items (e.g. smth like "Nancy, Andrew")?

I haven't found any setting for this in kendo docs for grid widget so I am wondering if there is any workaround?

## **Another setup**

I also have another column in the grid ("Last Name"), example is [here](https://dojo.telerik.com/adawoSOL).
In this case I have a custom multiselect widget for filter menu and after I select 2 items there ("Davolio" and "Fuller"):[image]

Then press Filter and I can observe the desired behaviour:[image]

But I want to achieve this with plain multi-check filter as in the problem above.

## **Edit**

I've also tried to manually sync filters, example [here](https://dojo.telerik.com/adawoSOL/3).

In short, in the `filterMenuInit` event of the grid I hook to the 'click' event in the filter menu with checkboxes, get checked values as array and set them into header cell filter AutoComplete widget:

```js
filterMenuInit: function(e) {
    const config = e.sender.options.columns.find(c => c.field === e.field);
    if (((config || {}).filterable || {}).multi) {
        const quickFilter = $('.k-filter-row .k-filtercell[data-field=' + e.field + '] input[data-role=autocomplete]').data('kendoAutoComplete');

        e.container.on('click', '[type=submit]', function() {
            const multiCheck = e.sender.thead.find('[data-field=' + e.field + ']').data('kendoFilterMultiCheck');
            if (!multiCheck || !quickFilter) return;
            const values = multiCheck.container
                .find('input[type=checkbox]:not(.k-check-all)')
                .filter((i, x) => x.checked)
                .map((i, x) => x.value)
                .get();

            if (values && values.length > 1) {
                quickFilter.value(values);
            }
        });
    }
},
```

I can see the desired result (e.g. "Nancy, Andrew") right after I click 'Filter' but it resets back to just 1st item ("Nancy") after `dataBound`.

This seems to occur due to the fact that the header filter cell input has MVVM binding to the grid filters: `<input data-bind="value: value"`. Removing this is no good either as it breaks a lot of stuff related to filtering.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you tried the [`columns.filterable.cell.template`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/columns.filterable.cell#columns.filterable.cell.template) parameter ?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown, yes I have it set to be a simple AutoComplete widget with the same datasource as menu filter. I see I can assign an array of values to that AutoComplete but that means I'll need to manually sync it and menu filter which seems like an error prone way to achieve the desired result

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown, your comment actually pushed me towards a partial solution, but it still is not complete and doesn't work - please take a look at edit with another example I made.